# Always propose a word when correcting a word in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

I wonder whether there is any way to always propose a word when correcting a word in Dragon NaturallySpeaking. For example, if I dictated "I wonder without", and said "select without", I want the word "whether" to be always present amongst the word suggestions:

Not good:

[image]

Good:

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that I know of. I have never heard of or read about a hack in a config file or other setting that would allow you to do such thing. FWIW, I've been using Dragon and reading in Dragon forums since 2007.

If it's even possible, this would be some serious messing with Dragon's algorithms that decide which words appear in the correction window. It would probably break a lot of other things.

If you always get this kind of mistake, why not create a macro for it that corrects it?

It would be something like:

```
HeardWord "select", "without"
SendKeys "whether", True
HeardWord "go", "back"
```